# Are epilators halachically allowed?

Tags: halacha, shaving

I just read on wikipedia that epilators were invented on a kibbutz in Israel.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilator

An epilator is a device that plucks hair out from the root.  Would it be OK for a man to use a device on his face? If not, would it be OK for a woman to shave her legs using this?

Comment: Why is your second question contingent on the answer to the first question's being "no"?

Comment: My conjecture: There's lots written about tweezing, and, well, this is just tweezing with battery power instead of elbow grease.

Comment: I always interpreted that it was OK for a woman to shave her legs, even with a straight razor (not ok for a man as it is cross dressing). So therefore a man shaving should be more extreme than a woman's.

Comment: I'm not aware on any restriction on a woman's shaving her legs.